# SQL Developer weird error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In the SQL Developer, I run this query, it gave me error : "table or view does not exist". 
I tried to discontinute first and login agin, still same error.

But I use TOAD to run same query, it works.

SQL Developer have any settings to cause this ?

My SQL Developer version is 3.0.04. I am losing confidence in this tool.

```
select * from myschema.codes0
```

Comment: To eliminate the obvious, are you connected as the same user (and to the same database) from both applications? Are you connected as `myschema` - in which case you don't need to specify that in the query; and if not does your user have select privileges on the table in `myschema`?

Comment: It's not a problem with SQL Developer itself, it is a problem with your connection to the DB or some preferences you have set. Do you really think Oracle would release an IDE that couldn't select from a table?

Answer (score 0):

As I do this in SQL Developer every day, it's not a problem with the tool. I'd say you're almost certainly logged in as a user that does not have privileges over `myschema`. What user are you logging in as?

Assuming codes0 is a table, this should tell you if you have select privileges over it:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_privs WHERE table_owner = 'MYSCHEMA' AND table_name = 'CODES0'
```